# Reset woocommerce orders to 0

Tags: woocommerce

Does anyone know how to reset order systems so order ids start from 0 again?

I have tried to delete all orders from woocommerce but new orders start from last one again?

Thanks

Comment: Is not possible as order numbers are imputed from the post Id that comes from wp_posts table in database. Now you can use one of this plugins: [Custom Order Numbers for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-order-numbers-for-woocommerce/) or [WooCommerce Sequential Order Numbers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers/) that should solve your problem as they will use a separate order number (different  from the post ID).

Answer (score 4):

My problem was solved by using the plugin [Custom Order Numbers for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-order-numbers-for-woocommerce/).

1. You need to **delete** all orders and leave only one order.
2. Now go into WooCommerce settings, you'll find a tab [Custom Order Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lHFZ.png).
3. Here input your desired custom order in [Sequential: Next order number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqkHN.png).
4. After, click on **Save Changes**.
5. Now click on [Remunerate Order tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebGy6.png).
6. Now click for [confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuOGH.png).

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

From within WooCommerce, there is no way you can reset the order numbers. There are some plugins that can do it.